# Why do some professors state on their website to contact them prior to applying for admission to a PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor

I've noticed some potential professors explicitly write to contact them prior to applying if interested in working with them. Why is that?

Comment: Are you referring to professors in a specific country?

Comment: This depends on country and maybe on field. It would be an unusual request in US, but possibly a requirement in Germany. Where are you applying?

Comment: Within the US it definitely depends on the field.

Comment: I am applying within the U.S. for a PhD in Geoscience/Atmospheric Science

Answer (score 4):

Probably to save you and them time, because in the past they have received many applications that were not suitable, or they are only interested in students with certain very specific skills.

You can write them a short and concise message summarizing your experience, skills, and why you are thinking of applying - maybe 4 bullet points - and asking whether you should make a formal application or whether you could talk to them to discuss.

Answer (score 2):

They may also not have funding this year, or are not looking to hire anyone, so better you find out now instead of in a few months after the application process that they cant hire you (depending whether you apply to the professor or to the school).

Maybe they are looking for a very particular candidate/skillset so they can advise whether you would even be worth considering.

Or they just want to see who can actually follow instructions. They can simplify their search by only considering those that showed some initiative and reached out to them.